# Grails groupProperty and order. How it works?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, ora-00979

I have this domain :

```
class Participation {
   ParticipationStatus status
}
class ParticipationStatus{
   String name
   Date creationDate
}
```

I create a query :

```
Participation.createCriteria().list{
   createAlias("status","statusAlias")
   order "statusAlias.creationDate"
   projections{
     groupProperty "id"    
   }
}
```

But I received an error : 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00979: N'est pas une expression GROUP BY

I 'm working 2 days ago on this query grrrr ! ;-)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every field you use in aggregate queries (the one using `projections`) should be either a `groupProperty`, or only an aggregate function argument (that is, in `projections` anyway).
In this example, try

```
Participation.createCriteria().list{
   createAlias("status","statusAlias")
   order "statusAlias.creationDate"
   projections{
     groupProperty "id"    
     groupProperty "statusAlias.creationDate"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it's working but the result is [[1,date object], [2, dateobject]] and would like receive only [1,2] (only ids)

Comment: You can't, if you're using `group by`. Grouping breaks the original order of records, so you can `order` only the resulting dataset - and you need to add the date field for that. OTOH, do you need grouping at all? If `id` is Grails' `id`, then it's unique anyway.